# Is there a way to split app/web.config into 2 files?

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, app-config

I currently use app/web.config to store Connection Strings for my database, which means on upgrade we do not touch the config files to preserve those strings.  However we now want to move to MVC5 and doing so requires all the library definitions to be updated within the app/web.config (we have both an App and a website with similar configuration).

So is it possible to split these files into two files so that I can update the library definitions whilst keeping intact my existing infrastructure to read out the connection strings from the .config files? Or is there another method to deal with this?

Comment: Alternatively to split up your configs, you can use the config transformation feature, which will modify your config depending on the selected build configuration. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes; you simply create a second file rather than including things inline, for example:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>
</configuration>
```

The `connections.config` file would start with `<connectionStrings>...</connectionStrings>`.

Comment: How would this work in terms of getting those connection strings? Currently I have a EF `DbContext` where I pass the connection string to in the constructor `public MyDataContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")`.  And would I just call it `connections.config` or would it be `app.connections.config`

Comment: Ahh.. Sorry it just clicked... So by specifying the external settings file C# will automatically pull it in when it reads the initial config file. The name doesnt really matter so long as `configSource` is correct?

Comment: @Chris correct - the settings framework does all the voodoo here, so you don't need to do anything other than a: create a new file , and b: tell `configSource` the name of that file.

Comment: Awesome, seems perfect, if I wanted to  store other things in `connections.config` i.e. call it `user.config` could I use a similar mechanism to import all the settings into the main one?

Comment: @Chris only one section per external file, but : "probably" - give it a go and find out ;p

Comment: Hi Marc, This worked great for `ConnectionStrings` but didnt work for `userSettings` - any ideas on that one?

Comment: @Chris odd; I *thought* it applied to all settings groups; is `userSettings` a top-level configuration group? where exactly is `userSettings` in the config file?

Comment: Yes its top level, the exception thrown is `{"The attribute 'configSource' cannot be specified because its name starts with the reserved prefix 'config' or 'lock'....}`

Comment: You are right, I had to just change where I was putting the configSource attribute. Thanks again