# How to use custom config/resources XML for services in C# MVVM

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, mvvm

Using MVVM and `Newtonsoft.Json` JSON library I am able to load my model resources from a JSON file like in `ConfigService` class I have something like this there:

`ConfigService.cs`

```
namespace app
{
    class ConfigService
    {
        public Model LoadJSON()
        {
            string modelContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TEMP\config.json");
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(modelContent);
        }
    }
}
```

In `Model` Class I have

```
namespace app
{
    public class Model
    {
       private string basemapLayerUri;
       public Model() { }

       public string BasemapLayerUri
        {
            get { return this.basemapLayerUri; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.basemapLayerUri)
                {
                    this.basemapLayerUri = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in `ViewModel.cs` I have

```
namespace App
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    { 
        private Model baseMapModel = null;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public ViewModel()
        {

                ConfigService config = new ConfigService();
                this.baseMapModel = config.LoadJSON();

        }
        public string BasemapUri
        {
            get { return baseMapModel.BasemapLayerUri; }
            set
            {
                this.baseMapModel.BasemapLayerUri = value;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is working fine. How can I do the same job with an XML file? I know App.XML can somehow handle this but I would like to have custom resource like `appconfig.xml` instead of `config.json` in the `Services` folder

Comment: is there a reason why you are not using the default App.config file ?

Comment: well I would like to separate configurations for different aspects of the application and not put them all in one place

Comment: What you're looking for is `XmlSerializer`

Comment: @MonaCoder you could split sections of the config into different files. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22686902/6138713